# How to define update criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a form with one input with one field - "companyName":

```
<form method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/edit_company/<%- company.name %>" method="post">    
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" value="<%- company.name %>">    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send!">           
</form>
```

How can I update company name in MongoDB with the specified criteria? How do I define this criteria?

mongoose query example:

```
Company.update({"some criteria": "some criteria"}, {$set: {name: req.body.companyName} });
```

Collection example before update:

```
> db.companies.findOne();
{
    "name" : "someName",
    "salt" : "0.8330190361011773",
    "_id" : ObjectId("53200580d0285e46618de6bc"),
    "created" : ISODate("2014-03-12T06:58:08.166Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: but where do you update your companyname??

Comment: in mongodb collection through mongoose

Comment: The criteria i.e your object id
=> Company.update({"_id": ObjectId("53200580d0285e46618de6bc")}, {$set: {name: req.body.companyName} });

Comment: thanks but how do I can transport this objectId to my form and then from form to my criteria? via hidden input?

Comment: yes, But that is a string not object id so you have to convert it into objectid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criteria i.e your object id

```
=> Company.update({"_id": ObjectId("53200580d0285e46618de6bc")}, {$set: {name:req.body.companyName} });
```

Comment: thanks, but need to consider that when retrieve object from mongo - we are retrieve a string, not some object, thats confused me

Comment: Every objectId would be in your session such that you can update the particular row's using that objectId.
The objectId's format is String, while you set a session or retrive it from session.